# Combining vlookup with getpivotdata, or another suggestion

Tags: nested, pivot-table, vlookup, excel-2013

I've searched and searched for an answer to this question, but everything I try gets me either a #REF! or a #NAME? error.

I have two worksheets, one contains a pivot table, the other contains a drop down menu and cells that need information pulled into them from the pivot table based on what information the drop down menu is showing.

For example: the drop-down menu contains a project ID, the cells (on the same worksheet as the drop-down menu) need to pull in budget information from the pivot table that is on a separate worksheet. Whenever I change the project ID through the drop-down menu, I need these cells that reference the pivot table to update based on that project ID.

I've tried combining a vlookup within a getpivotdata, but every way I try to do this I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! It only took me 3 days :D

=GETPIVOTDATA("AMT",'Pivot Table'!$A$3,"PROJ_ID",Table!K8,"SOURCE_TYPE","COST","ACCT_ID","Labor","SOURCE","BUD")